# R: Finding which x = 1 in my function in R

Tags: r, montecarlo

I am currently working on a problem in R.

I have defined a function:

`

```
Function(x,z){
     x = rbinom(100,1,0.5)
     y = rbeta(length(x),0.5,2)
     return(x*y^2 + y)
    }
```

`

I am trying to write a loop which tells me if x == 1 then it prints the outputs of my function and vice versa for x == 0.

However, I am quite stuck on this and was wondering is there a function or short cut to solve this?

I am unable to get a for or if loop to work as I am new to R and was wondering is there a built in function which finds which x == 1 or x == 0 are in my function and if so shows me the output. For e.g i have 3 x = 0  terms and their function outputs are 2, 4, 6 then I would like to know which x == 0 terms gave these outputs etc.

Comment: Why does your function accept an argument named `x=` and then immediately overwrite it with `rbinom(100,1,0.5)`? Why is `z` ignored? While it seems tangential to your question, the function itself is a bit confusing. Further, what is your desired output? I tend to "never" `print` something from a function, as doing so is practically (if not technically) unusable by the calling environment, perhaps you intend to return a list or vector with various values partitioned on `x` within `0` and `1`?

Comment: The question seems a bit unclear at the moment, but does `split(x*y^2 + y, x)` give you the values you want, i.e. the current return values listed by whether x was zero or one?